# Get $f(x)=u_x\frac{x}{u}$ from ODE for $u$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider the Cauchy-Euler ODE
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}x^2u_{xx}+xu_x-u=0.
\end{align*}
Guessing $u(x)=Cx^n$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)Cx^n+nCx^n-Cx^n=0,
\end{align*}
which we can solve to get
\begin{align*}
n_1&=-2,\\
n_2&=1.
\end{align*}

Given initial conditions and boundary behavior, we can pin down a unique solution.

---

*I'm really interested in the function $$f(x)=u_x\frac{x}{u}.$$ Given the solution for $u$, we can compute $f$ to be $f(x)=n$, which is constant!*

**Q: I wonder whether I can find $f$, without solving the ODE first?**

---

Set $f=u_x\frac{x}{u}$. Then, $u_x=\frac{fu}{x}$ and $u_{xx}=\frac{f_xu}{x}+\frac{fu_x}{x}-\frac{fu}{x^2}$. The ODE then turns into
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\left(xf_xu+xfu_x-fu\right)+fu-u=0.
\end{align*}
Dividing this ODE by $u$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\left(xf_x+f^2-f\right)+f-1=0.
\end{align*}
If I *assume* $f_x=0$, then I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}f^2+\frac{1}{2}f-1=0,
\end{align*}
which is a normal quadratic equation with solutions
\begin{align*}
f_1&=-2,\\
f_2&=1.
\end{align*}
These are precisely the solutions I expected from the previous calculations.

---

*However, I had to assume $f_x=0$. I only knew this because I already knew the solution.*

**Why doesn't the second approach work? Is there a way to compute $f(x)$ without first solving the ODE for $u(x)$?**

Comment: If you solve the corresponding DE for $f$ and use the initial conditions, it should turn out to be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to your ODE is
$$
u(x)=Ax+Bx^{-2}
$$
and so
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{3 B}{A x^3+B}
$$
which is not in general constant. That is why you do not find $f_x=0$ directly from the ODE.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that $f$ is a constant for *any* $u$ which satisfies the given equation is false. Indeed,

$$u(x) = \frac{x^3 + 1}{x^2}$$

certainly satisfies the equation, but using that $u$ we have

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^3-2}{x^3+1} $$

Now, it's certainly true that *some* $u$ which satisfy the original equation make $f$ constant. In particular, it seems you were considering the $x^n$ solution. In general,

$$ u(x) = ax + bx^{-2} $$

so if we force one of $a,b$ to be zero, then we have the desired identity. We can get those by imposing the initial conditions $ u(0) = 0 $ for $b$ to vanish, and $ u(\infty) = 0 $ for $a$ to vanish.

In fact, setting $f'$ to zero gives an equation for $u$ with solution

$$u(x) = \alpha x^\beta$$

showing that this result is independent of the original equation for $u$.